# Creating segments on a road using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-online

[image]

How can I  create 1 KM segments along the road as indicated in the attached picture using ArcGIS? Something like buffer but like segments and of course the road in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the line into separate segments every 1km using the "Split" function on the editor menu in ArcMap, like so: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-existing-features/splitting-lines-at-a-specified-distance-or-percentage.htm

And then use the Buffer tool (in ArcToolbox, not the editor menu) To create the polygonal segments. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm If you have an advanced license, the FLAT option in the buffer tool will create square ends that end where the segment ends. If not, you will get semicircular ends that overlap each other by your buffer distance. Fixing that without an advanced license is a bit kludgy, but this should work: Select every other polygon (if there are a lot of them you could try selecting the ones with even OID values or something), export them to a separate feature class, and delete them from the original feature class. Then use the Union tool in toolbox to combine them back, but this will cause the overlaps to get created as separate polygons. Then you can select them based on their area and delete them.